# Issue connecting over RDP when on Windows VPN

Tags: windows-7, rdp, vpn

I have an issue that just began today and not sure what the cause is (I've been able to successfully connect this way for several years). On my Windows 7 box, I have a VPN set up in Windows. Today I was on the VPN and logged into an RDP session with no problem. I disconnected from the RDP session and the VPN. A few minutes later, I got back on the VPN, and when attempting several times to connect to the server over RDP again, I got several error messages:

```
Because of a protocol error this session will be disconnected
Because of a protocol error detected at the client (code 0x1104)
Because of a protocol error detected at the client this session will be disconnected
```

When attempting to browse a website in Chrome while connected to the VPN, no stylesheets would load. Google Drive lost connectivity, though Dropbox did not. Firefox displayed the following message:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an
>   invalid or unsupported form of compression.

I am also seeing SSL Protocol errors in Firefox, and other errors when secure (port 443) requests are made. Disconnecting from the VPN made browsing normally possible again and Google Drive came back.

I have another Windows VPN which I connected to - same issues.

The only thing I can think of is I earlier added a Windows Firewall rule to open ports 53, 88, 138,137,139, 389, 445, 636. I deleted the rule, rebooted, and even turned off the firewall and disabled Microsoft Security Essentials but the issue did not go away.

One other thing - for servers where I do not have to be on a VPN, I can remote desktop fine.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is the VPN client (which one are you running?) on the server (what version is it?) via which you connect that has gone corrupt.

If you have any physical access to it then I suggest checking up on the settings, resetting it, perhaps even checking network connections on the NICs if everything is in order if your ISP changed your IP or the server has moved to another location.

Try the last post in [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/protocol-error-0x1104-connecting-2003-servers-t1863400.html) thread

edit: Oh, also don't forget to check up on event log... and having your firewall turned off is not very safe ;)

Comment: I'm connecting to this particular VPN through a connection I made in Network and Sharing Center. I created a VM and set up a connection the exact same way and it works flawlessly. Just can't get my main box to work properly.